# Problems with Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have one problem with Navigation Drawer in Android.

I am in Empty activity and I need pass to Navigation Drawer, my code in 
Empty activity is

```
final Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent new_from = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(new_from);
        }
    });
```

This code is correct.

The Drawer class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

now, in the Drawer, the problem is this line

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The last line closes my application.

PD: All activities are in the Manifest.

Thanks and happy day

Comment: put all your code here and the stacktrace as well

Comment: You may have Actionbar error, use NoActionBar theme for the same activity

Comment: where is your stacktrace????? what is the error? Put your theme here as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added toolbar and set it as action bar programatically you need to change your style

Go to manifest and edit your Drawer activity tag like this:

```
<activity 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my program work right now :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide all the informations about this issue, I will address this question assuming that you didn't set the proper conditions for Navigation Drawer and most likely you have issue with conflict in setting your toolbar in activity and default theme.

If you want to create Navigation drawer with toolbar in the manner you already wrote in MainActivity (setSupportActionBar(toolbar)), you need to change app theme.

You can do it in Manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

You can also change that in res/values/styles.xml:

With custom theme

```
<style name = "AppTheme" parent = "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Or just replace theme (better way is from manifest for this):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

If you want to set up Navigation Drawer in some other way, check this links for more help about this topic:

[StackOverflow - How to create Android Custom Striped Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44136856/8024660)
[Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
[JournalDev](http://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)
[TeamTreeHouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android)